# Taking a more functional approach

Tags: java, functional-programming

I currently have this method (this is basically the real one, I just renamed variables and objects)

```
private void myMethod(
      final InputMessage inputMessage,
      final String id) {
    try {
        final Map<String, String> result =
              jdbcTemplate.query(
                  QUERY /* sql */, 
                  ROW_EXTRACTOR /* ResultSetExtractor */, 
                  id /* args */
              );

        if (result != null) {
            inputMessage.setParam1(result.get("param1"));
            inputMessage.setId(result.get("description")); // Insert description
            return;
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error(...);
    }

    final String param1 = ...

    inputMessage.setParam1(param1);
    inputMessage.setId(id); // Insert the ID
}
```

I'd like to take a more functional approach for this. Just to try it out.
I tought about different solutions but none of them is able to maintain the same logic.

How would you do that? Is it possible at all?
I'm on `Java 8`, but you can throw in `Java 11` classes and methods if necessary.

It isn't necessary to "convert" the entire method, I'm more interested in the part after the `result` extraction. However it is tightly coupled to the `try - catch` block.

Comment: Downvote and come here to say why, I'll be more than happy to delete the question or discuss about it.

Comment: not a functional approach but you can declare a rowMapper :  InputMessage inputMessage =
              jdbcTemplate.query(
                  QUERY /* sql */, 
                  new RowMapper<InputMessage> { // here map your input fields },
                 args
              );

Comment: upvoting for interesting approach; I believe these questions are valuable for a normal stackoverflow user programming in java

Comment: @AsierAranbarri I really don't understand the downvotes. I am a seasoned Java developer, and when I have free time I like experimenting with functional programming to see if it results in better readability. Which is always a pro.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 I cannot let the exception escape. This is perfectly fine for the kind of software I'm writing. I'm not under transaction. Just for your interest, this is used in conjuction with an Apache Camel flow.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 well if the downvotes comes for non-in-scope matters, it is always better to ask before. Like you just did!

Comment: It is hard to limit people to what you think should be in-scope. but void methods, mutating inputs, and exception-handling are all anti-FP here. I'm not a camel user but if you're plugging into a framework i would be surprised if there wasn't an exceptionhandling mechanism.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 I understand. However the question doesn't ask "should I be in transaction?" or "should I modify the input object or not?". I'm not criticising, but I think you got the point. When you deal with software someone else wrote you're always limited in some ways.

Comment: I have not voted on the question, but the description of the downvote button starts with, "_This question does not show any research effort_". I think that's a fair assessment. A better question for SO would show your own attempt(s) e.g. here is my attempt at converting procedural code X into functional code Y; but Y does not satisfy criteria A,B,C from X. How can I achieve the requirements of my X code using a more functional approach similar to my Y code? The advantages I would like to achieve from functional programming are D,E,F.

Comment: You may also be interested in what https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ has to offer.

Comment: @jaco0646 that is a fair point. However, as I said, every solution I tried did change the semantic of the method, which for me was not acceptable, and because of that I decided to not post them. It seems, reading the answers, that this isn't possible without changing the way the method behave, so probably I got the answer I was looking for. It is perfectly fine to answer "you cannot do that, you'd need to rewrite it from scratch"

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer return a new `InputMessage` from method rather than pass it as a parameter. Assuming you have constructor for `InputMessage` with 2 params it will looks like:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(result)
    .map(map -> new InputMessage(map.get("param1"), map.get("description")))
    .orElse(new InputMessage("id", "param1"));
```

Comment: Good idea! I would have applied it, but unfortunately the real object is composed of 15 properties, and I cannot touch it.

Comment: @LppEdd yes, 15 props won't look so concise :)  You can put `inputMessage` filling in a separate method for example

Comment: Wouldn't I need two methods in this case? One for the "ok" part, and one for the "post-catch" part? There is always the exception problem which seems insurmountable, as `JdbcTemplate` might throw one.

Comment: And btw, a "You need to re-do it entirely" is a valid answer too ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```java
private void myMethod(final InputMessage inputMessage, final String id) { 
    final Map<String, String> result = null;
    try {
        result = jdbcTemplate.query(
             QUERY /* sql */, 
             ROW_EXTRACTOR /* ResultSetExtractor */, 
             id /* args */
        );
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error(...);
    }

    if (result != null)
        setParams(inputMessage, result.get("param1"), result.get("description")) 
    else
        setParams(inputMessage, param1, id);
}

public void setParams(final InputMessage inputMessage, String param1, String param2) {
    inputMessage.setParam1(param1);
    inputMessage.setId(param2);
}
```

Comment: The shorthand if requires a statement to be used. This would result in a compilation error unfortunately

Comment: This won't compile because `result` scope is inside the `try` block only. And I think we are back to the imperative style.

Comment: Just declare it outside the `try-catch` block, you are checking if its null anyway. I edited it again.

Answer (score 0):

When querying database results you should use the Optional class in Java in order to avoid NullPointerExceptions.  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html here is some further documentation).

For example, the following piece of code:

```
final Map<String, String> result =
          jdbcTemplate.query(
              QUERY /* sql */, 
              ROW_EXTRACTOR /* ResultSetExtractor */, 
              id /* args */
          );
```

Should not return null but much rather an `Optional<Map<String,String>>`, then you would be able to write the code in a functional manner like this:

```
result.ifPresent(res -> {
            inputMessage.setParam1(res.get("param1"));
            inputMessage.setId(res.get("description")); // Insert description
        });
```

This would also help you to take out the try-catch statement which is unnecessary here.

Also it is a good practice to seperate the data fetching functionality to the DAO layer and do operations on the fetched objects in the Service layer. Please find more documentation with regards to that here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern

Comment: Using `Optional` only inside the `try` block is not what I'm looking for unfortunately. This just swap the `null` check for a `ifPresent` call. Thanks anyway for the answer!